# Why am I unable to rewrite exact data from a table using REGEX_EXTRACT in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I have a campaign UTM table on Google Data Studio that I would like to re-write using [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) so that the table only shows certain information.

This is the table that I would like to re-write data from:

| Campaign |
| --- |
| ID-google-campaign-20210212-all-en-en-HYPY-campaignname0 |
| ID-google-campaign-20210522-all-en-en-MHTP |
| ID-google-campaign-20200204-all-en-en-PPOY |
| ID-google-campaign-20200422-all-en-en-YMYP |
| ID-google-campaign-20200223-all-en-en-YPPT-campaignname1 |

I would like to only present data with the various campaign name codes if they appear in the format: HXXX, PXXX, MXXX, YXXX, VXXX or CXXX.

Based on the above table, I would only like to have these values show:

| Campaign |
| --- |
| HYPY |
| MHTP |
| PPOY |
| YMYP |
| YPPT |

I've tried a few variants of the regex but the data doesn't pull correctly, or it shows a portion of the data.

Some examples:

**Showing Null**

`(H|P|M|Y|V|C)[A-Z]{3}`

`^*(H|P|M|Y|V|C)[A-Z]{3}`

`(H|P|M|Y|V|C){3}`

**Shows the first letter of the data**

`(H|P|M|Y|V|C)`

| Campaign |
| --- |
| H |
| M |
| P |
| Y |
| Y |

Using the Regex testers online shows that it works but it somehow doesn't filter on Google Data Studio.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the regex pattern `[^-]+$`:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Campaign, "[^-]+$")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It gives a null however on datastudio on all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
-([HPMYVC][A-Z]{3})(?:-|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIzgbR/3). Note that only the part wrapped with a pair of unescaped parentheses (a capturing group) will be output.

*Details*:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `([HPMYVC][A-Z]{3})` - Group 1: `[HPMYVC]` matches `H`, `P`, `M`, `Y`, `V` or `C` and then `[A-Z]{3}` matches three uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?:-|$)` - `-` or end of string.
  `